# When creating a new git repository with 40,000 things, so I have to uncomment each in the COMMIT file?

Tags: git, commit

Okay, I am confused! I have a directory with ~40,000 files, and I created a git repository. I add all the files with:

git add .

then when I type "git commit" I get a 40,000 line text file that opens, and EVERY line is commented. If I close this file without uncommenting anything, it does not perform any commit at all. However, if I uncomment just a single line from this file, it SEEMS to commit all 40,000 files. Is this correct, this seems confusing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments are just showing you what files are being committed.

You need to add a commit message; that's what the editor is prompting you for. Try typing "My first commit" and saving.

Comment: Just for the record, this is all totally clear from the text coming *before* the list of files, which the OP seems to have missed: "Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit. ... Changes to be committed: <list>"

Answer (score 2):

Use `git commit -m "commit message"` when you have just a single line of commit message ( which I feel you mostly should)

Omit the `-m` if you have a  large message and you want git to present you your editor so that you can type the message. Ignore the comments ( they are there to help you see what you are committing), just enter your message, save and quit your editor to commit.

Comment: If this question were about how to write commit messages, I'd give you a -1 for suggesting that commit messages should usually be one line. They should usually not. Almost every change is substantial enough to warrant more than 80 characters of explanation. (I'm speaking in particular about repositories which are shared with others, which is ultimately true of most real code. That one line might be clear to you, but it probably won't be to the next person to see it.)

Comment: @Jefromi - I said "when you have just a single line of commit message. And a side note in the brackets that *I FEEL* it should mostly be one line.

Comment: Yes, and I disagree with your feeling, but understand that it's not the focus of the answer, so I commented but of course did not -1.

Answer (score 0):

Correct; git doesn't care about the contents of the commit message, as long as there is something uncommented. It doesn't check that your message has anything to do with the files you committed.